# Continuous scrolling with jquery waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to follow this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7907792/1653234) to create an infinite scrolling technique. In my example code, why is it not working? I would like to simulate that content be loaded each time I reach the bottom. Currently it only works a finite amount.

After reading docs I believe that I am not refreshing correctly. I suspect the [recalculation of the "trigger point"](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#doc-refresh) isn't firing. I am not sure how to make it work.

In my example, I am simulating new content being loaded by calling the getMore() function that appends more Divs . I want to achieve the effect that page never ends.

Please see: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy6ta/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="viewport-content">
        <div id="messages">
            <p>Some text here.</p>
            <p>Some text here.</p>
            <p>Some text here.</p>
            <p>Some text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="waypoint"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pageId=0;
    $("#waypoint").waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            getMore(++pageId);
        }
    }, {
        context: '.viewport .viewport-content',
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
    });

    function getMore(myPageId) {
        console.log("Loading page " + myPageId);
        for (var i=1; i<11; i++) {
            $("#messages").append("<p>Page " + myPageId + ". Row " + i + ".</p>");
        }

        $.waypoints('refresh');
    }
});
```

**demo.html (An example of the Infinite Scroll Shortcut Demo)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
                * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    body {
      font-size:16px;
      line-height:1.5;
      color:#6a6272;
      background:#d5c5e5;
      padding-bottom:16px;
      font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .inner {
      width:460px;
      padding:0 10px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4 {
      font-family:"PT Serif", serif;
      font-weight:normal;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size:53px;
      color:#444a50;
    }

    h2 {
      text-align:center;
      background:#6a6272;
      color:#eae2f2;
      font-size:24px;
    }

    pre {
      white-space:pre-wrap;
      font-size:14px;
      background:#fff;
      padding:10px;
    }

    code {
      font-family:"Ubuntu Mono", monospace;
    }

    p, pre, ul, .example, dl {
      margin-top:16px;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size:24px;
    }

    ol {
      margin-left:12px;
    }

    li {
      margin-top:6px;
    }

    .steps {
      background:#6a6272;
      color:#eae2f2;
      padding:16px 0;
      margin-top:16px;
    }

    .options {
      background:#6a6272;
      color:#eae2f2;
      padding:16px 0;
      margin-top:16px;
    }

    dt {
      font-weight:bold;
      color:#fff;
      margin-top:6px;
    }

    dd {
      margin-left:16px;
    }

    .fn {
      color:#111;
    }
    .kw {
      color:#a33;
    }
    .str {
      color:#3a3;
    }
    .cm {
      color:#33a;
    }
    .key {
      color:#939;
    }

    p code, li code, dl code {
      padding:0 2px;
      background:#eae2f2;
    }

    .steps li code, .options dl code {
      background:#444a50;
    }

    .options strong, .steps strong {
      color:#fff;
    }

    pre code {
      color:#888;
    }

    .infinite-container {
      width:480px;
      margin-left:-20px;
      overflow:hidden;
      position:relative;
    }

    .infinite-container.infinite-loading:after {
      content:"Loading...";
      height:30px;
      line-height:30px;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      text-align:center;
      background:#6a6272;
      color:#eae2f2;
    }

    .infinite-item {
      float:left;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background:#444a50;
      margin:20px 0 20px 20px;
    }
    .infinite-item:nth-child(3n) {
      background:#6a6272;
    }
    .infinite-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
      background:#eae2f2;
    }

    .infinite-more-link {
      visibility:hidden;
    }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="inner example">
        <h3>Example</h3>
            <div class="infinite-container">
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
                <div class="infinite-item"></div>
            </div>
            <a href="demo.html" class="infinite-more-link">More</a>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/waypoints-infinite.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.infinite-container').waypoint('infinite');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://iscrolljs.com/

Comment: hi @medokr just to check if you managed to resolve it ultimately? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: hi @Slay, Unfortunately not. I decided not to use this tool after failing to get it working.

Comment: @medokr thanks for the reply. Managed to get it working. check out my posted solution below. hope it helps in future projects. :D

Answer (score 1):

I was wanting to do the same type of thing and ended switching from Waypoints to Bullseye:

http://pixeltango.com/resources/web-development/jquery-bullseye-viewport-detection-events/

So you could do something like this:

```
var myPageId = 1;
function getMore(e)
{
  for (var i=1; i<11; i++)
  {
    $("#messages").append("<p>Page " + myPageId + ". Row " + i + ".</p>");
  }
  myPageId++;
}

$('#waypoint').bind('enterviewport', getMore ).bullseye();
```

It will call your 'getMore' function every time the #waypoint element enters the viewport, so when it jumps down the page and then reenters you get a new callback!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working. Thought i should share it here.

I used **jQuery Waypoints 3.1.1**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageId=0;
    var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: $("#waypoint"),
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'down') {
                getMore(++pageId);
                Waypoint.refreshAll();
            }
        },
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
    });

    function getMore(myPageId) {
        console.log("Loading page " + myPageId);
        for (var i=1; i<11; i++) {
            $("#messages").append("<p>Page " + myPageId + ". Row " + i + ".</p>");
        }
    }
});
```

(1) Note the changes in instantiation of waypoint. (new Waypoint....)

(2) Call Waypoint.refreshAll() to refresh the waypoints after appended.

Hope it helps. Above code snippet is not tested, but theoretically should work.

Slay

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle, but getMore() is called 1000+ times everytime you scroll down, how to limit this so getMore() only get's called once for each scroll below the waypoint? If you comment out `Waypoint.refreshAll()` getMore() is called only once, but the refresh when scrolling down more is really sluggish: http://jsfiddle.net/75g6cap2/45/

Comment: hi @GiantElk just saw your response. are you still looking for a solution to this?